# Regex Not equal

Tags: c#, regex

I have seen many examples on here and other sites pertaining to my issue.  However, non seem to work.

I am trying to create a simple address parser, and need to check each word in the address to shove into the proper column.

For example:
I have an address 1234 N MAIN

I need each word separated.  My numeric check seems to work fine, however I am having an issue with the NOT EQUAL part of my regex.

Works:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(words[0], @"^\d+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Does not work:

```
&& (!Regex.IsMatch(words[1], @"(N|S|E|W)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

You would think this would work, but it keeps matching the values instead.

UPDATE:

A literal text compare solved this for me.

```
        string[] testDir = { "N", "S", "W", "E","NORTH","SOUTH","WEST","EAST","NORTHWEST","NORTHEAST","SOUTHWEST","SOUTHEAST"};


if testDir.Contains(words[1], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        strStreetNum = words[0];
                        strPreDir = words[1];
                        strStreetName = words[2];
                    }
else if !testDir.Contains(words[1], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        strStreetNum = words[0];
                        strStreetName = words[1] + " " + words[2];
                    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to have the `!` in there? `!Regex.IsMatch(words[1]...`

Comment: I guess you mean Regex.IsMatch(words[1], @"[^NSEW]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase). But it's completely not clear from the question

Comment: I am trying to say where NOT equal to.

Comment: What is `words`? Is it an array of what you consider words (in this case `1234`, `N` and `MAIN`? Do you need a regex that tests if a certain word matches only digits, then another one that matches only either the letter N, S, E or W and then another one that matches.. what?
You could do this in a single regex. Clarify what you want to achieve and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Did you read my OP?  Not sure how I could have made it clearer. Do [] mean something else in C#?

Comment: This is why I don't like posting on here.  Such hostility... NOT EQUAL.  I am look for the regex version of NOT EQUAL....

Comment: People are trying to help you man - I'm sorry to say that the question is not really very clear.  We don't know what "it keeps matching the values instead" means.  We don't know the contents of the words array.  We don't know what you're expecting the code to do.  We don't know what it's doing instead.  We don't know what "Works" means.  We don't know what "Does not work" means, etc.  Is the problem that you expect Regex.IsMatch("N", @"(N|S|E|W)") to return false, but it's returning true?  There are already a few comments telling you how to do "Not equal to" in a regex

Comment: ... wow. The contents are 1234 n main. 1234 = words[0], n = words[1], main = words[2].  I only see one comment even related to Regex, not a few. I would love to quantify the entire string at once, but I can't.  I can't account for every variation I am seeing. It is much easier to break the address apart and check each "word" in a string array. Maybe I worded "I need each word separated" incorrectly.  I am already splitting the address into an array, then checking each element. The "words" can be anything from suite,ste,unit,bldg,building,etc.  to an actual number to an actual street.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question as asked, although I don't believe it's the solution to the problem you're having.

The ^ character, when used as the first character in a bracket expression will negate the character set found within those brackets.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ae5bf541(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ae5bf541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example: if you want to match "Not a number" you can write [^0-9]

If you want to match anything that isn't N, S, E, or W you would write [^NSEW]

Comment: Right, but it would find the "n" in "building" though, correct?  OK, should I use word groups? "N" or "NORTH" being it's own word, and so on and so forth for "E" "EAST", etc?

Comment: Let's try it and see:  Regex.Matches("building", "[^NSEW]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); matches "b, u, i, l, d, i, g"  - so every character except for the n.

Comment: All I am doing is looking for keywords and letters. In the address 1234 N MAIN. I check the first "words" to see if it is numeric, if it is it goes into the streetnum variable.  I check the second "words" to see if it matches n,s,e,w,ne,nw,se,sw,south,east,west,north, etc... if it does then it goes into the predir variable.

Comment: Perhaps a regex isn't the solution to your problem then.  For example - if someone wrote the word "nothing" then your regex would find a match - 'n' matches the 'n' in nothing (twice, actually).  Maybe you want a literal text comparison?

Comment: I have been leaning towards that lately.  This seems to be to convoluted for regex.  I am seeing some crazy data entry for the addresses, and it needs to be flexible.

Comment: Yes, a literal text comparison in that case would be better, even though you can do it in regex too using anchors. With more info people could determine if Regex or literal string comparison is better or something else maybe, but seeing as OP is uncooperative and hostile towards people trying to help, I'm out.

Comment: You were the one who started with the hostility.  If don't want a taste of your own medicine try being nicer.